# display video to a html page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, video

i have an application in which i browse a video and store that in a folder and save the path  to a database.

the path is like:

```
http://dc620x_abcd/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/rq/ref/1.mp4
```

on a next page i want to display the same video in an html page. i tried using `iFrame` of Html as

```
 <iframe id="frame1" runat="server" visible="false" style="height: 222px; width: 482px;">
                </iframe>



Finalpath = filepath + filename;
                frame1.Visible = true;
                frame1.Attributes.Add("embed src", Finalpath);
```

but it doesnt provide much help as it doesn't provide the video embedded in an iFrame(instead of playing the video in an iframe it ask for the download ).
can i make the video to be played in an `iframe` or what are the other ways to perform the same task. thanks for any assistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the html5 video tag:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://dc620x_abcd/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/rq/ref/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: sit it shows an error no video with supported format and mime type found . i have already registered it in iis the .mp4 format. what is this error?

Comment: if you using firefox, you need the video in ogv format. You can have two source tags in the video tag, one to the mp4 video en one to the ogv.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use video tags http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp
Or some video player http://videojs.com/